# Osmdroid Use local storage system for tiles

Tags: android, osmdroid

In earlier versions, osmdroid did use local storage for caching tiles. Is there a way to use the earlier caching system in 5.6.5? I think you have to use TileWriter instead of SqlWriter, but how to do this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MapTileProviderBasics](https://osmdroid.github.io/osmdroid/javadocs/osmdroid-android/release/index.html) and pass TileWriter instance in the constructor.

> public MapTileProviderBasic(final Context pContext, final ITileSource pTileSource, final IFilesystemCache cacheWriter)

```
MapTileProviderBasic tileProvider = new MapTileProviderBasic(getApplicationContext(), yourTileSource, new TileWriter());

mapView.setTileProvider(tileProvider);
```